# Facebook API - Infinite Loop during resquest

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use Facebook PHP SDK, but if i resquest some permission, the app generate a loop redirect until error. Someone know why ? Following the code. Thanks.

```
***<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
));


// permitir upload de fotos
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user)
{
        $permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");

        if (!array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0])) {

                header( "Location: " . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "publish_stream")) );
                exit;
        }

        echo "Pode publicar as fotos";

} else {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
        header("Location: $loginUrl");
        exit;
}***
```

Comment: Why are you checking for `publish_stream` permission? that was deprecated in favour of publish_actions some time ago - is the current documentation telling you to use publish_stream? if so can you add a link here please?

Comment: Hi Igy! I followed this url http://www.douglaspasqua.com/2012/05/15/facebook-app-requisitando-permissoes-pela-api-do-php/

Comment: I would suggest you to use facebook php sdk 4: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4

Comment: That link is 2.5 years old - i strongly recommend using the current documentation to make sure what you're trying to do is still possible